# How to calculate the time difference between two string-formatted datetimes?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to subtract two columns on a dataset which have string times in order to get a time value for statistical analysis.
Basically, TOC is start time and IA is end time.
Something is slightly wrong:

```
dfc = pd.DataFrame(zip(*[TOC,IA]),columns=['TOC','IA'])
print (dfc)

dfc.['TOC']= dfc.['TOC'].astype(dt.datetime)
dfc['TOC'] = pd.to_datetime(dfc['TOC'])
dfc['TOC'] = [time.time() for time in dfc['TOC']]
```

Comment: Provide a sample of your dataframe using `dfc.head(10).to_dict()` and include your expected output. Also, your code seems to have typos/invalid lines. Did you mean to write `dfc["TOC"]` (without the dot after `dfc`) instead of `dfc.["TOC"]` ?

Comment: {'Date': {0: '01/01/2013', 1: '01/01/2013', 2: '01/01/2013', 3: '01/01/2013'},
 'Station Area': {0: 'Tallaght', 1: 'Tara St', 2: 'Finglas', 3: 'Tara St'},
 'Clinical Status': {0: 'Non ProQa Class', 1: 'Bravo', 2: 'Delta', 3: 'Bravo'},
 'TOC': {0: '00:02:09', 1: '00:02:41', 2: '00:13:52', 3: '00:06:58'},
 'ORD': {0: '00:04:14', 1: '00:14:41', 2: '00:16:26', 3: '00:22:33'},
 'MOB': {0: '00:04:58', 1: '00:15:04', 2: '00:16:51', 3: '00:22:59'},
 'IA': {0: '00:10:16', 1: '00:18:10', 2: '00:25:06', 3: '00:34:48'},
 'LS': {0: nan, 1: nan, 2: '00:29:36', 3: nan},

Answer (score 0):

Convert the columns to datetime before subtracting:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(dfc["IA"], format="%H:%M:%S")-pd.to_datetime(dfc["TOC"], format="%H:%M:%S")

0   0 days 00:08:07
1   0 days 00:15:29
2   0 days 00:11:14
3   0 days 00:27:50
dtype: timedelta64[ns]
```